# Invalid expression term 'else' after i typed it the second time

Tags: c#

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("what is the value of 3 + 8?");
    number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    if (number == 11)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("well done");
        Console.WriteLine("press enter once");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    else;
    {
        Console.WriteLine("its 11 u idiot!!!");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    Console.WriteLine("what is the value of 23132-23131?");
    number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    if (number == 1);
    {
        Console.WriteLine("oh yeah!");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    else;
    {
        Console.WriteLine("u r such a noob!");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

What is the problem there??? Visual studio told me invalid expression term 'else' after the second 'else' i typed and i don't know why?

Comment: You have semicolon on your IF ELSE

Comment: and the indentation just... misleading.

Comment: Keep in mind the `else ; { .. }` is perfectly valid syntax though it probably won't do what you expect (the `;` terminates the `else` block and the braced bit is therefore just a scoped block that executes always). The real issue is the `if ();` which is a conditional with an empty block. The `{...}` following that is again a valid scoping block but, unfortunately, the `else` no longer has an active `if` to connect to

Answer (score 2):

Remove the semicolon after each of the two `else` keywords:

```
else   // was else;
```

and after the `if` line:

```
if (number == 1)   // was if (number == 1);
```

In addition, you should actually declare `number`:

```
var number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

This is the ***final version*** of code that should work:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("what is the value of 3 + 8?");
    var number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    if (number == 11)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("well done");
        Console.WriteLine("press enter once");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("its 11 u idiot!!!");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    Console.WriteLine("what is the value of 23132-23131?");
    number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    if (number == 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("oh yeah!");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("u r such a noob!");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: @JonathanTan : you are missing data type for `number` too

Comment: after removing semicolon and } ,Visual studio say: expect { and ;

Comment: `var number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());`

Comment: thought i typed that

Comment: @Jonathan, DarkKnight gave no indication that you should remove `}`. Just the semiciolons.

Comment: @paxdiablo ok just the semicolons

Comment: @paxdiablo but vs still expect the use of semicolon after else and still say invalid expression 'else'

Comment: @Jonathan, let's make this clear. There are exactly three semicolons that need to disappear. One at the end of the `if` line and one at the end of each of the `else` lines. If it's complaining about the `else`, that's *probably* because you haven't removed the `if` one.

Comment: Dark, I tried to make the answer as specific/detailed as possible, hope you don't mind.

Comment: You ended up writing a whole guide for starters @paxdiablo. I have not seen many like you with combination of huge reputation and heaps of patience. Ofcourse, I dont mind. Thanks much! :)

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this

```
int  number;
Console.WriteLine("what is the value of 3 + 8?");
number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
if (number == 11)
{
    Console.WriteLine("well done");
    Console.WriteLine("press enter once");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("its 11 u idiot!!!");
    Console.ReadLine();
}

Console.WriteLine("what is the value of 23132-23131?");
number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

if (number == 1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("oh yeah!");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("u r such a noob!");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: So the whole "declare variables when you need them and no earlier" craze totally passed you by? :-)